# interactive jasper reports

Tags: jasper-reports

I am using jasper reports in my project to generate html reports. But the generated reports are static. Now we want to add some interactive features in it, like simple sorting and searching of columns. This is preferably to be done the client side. How can this be achieved ? So far I have tried to embed jquery into the generated report with no luck. Does jasper report provide such kind of functionality?

Answer (score 0):

Use parameters and re compile the report every time you want to filter  the data.

Answer (score 0):

With your meaning of the word "interactive", nope that is not possible. A report is only a report - a presentation medium that shows data in such manner that is required by the business rule. You can format data here. You can stylize it, add image and what not. A client side application is probably what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Well, your exact requirement can be achieved if you publish the Jasper Reports on the Jasper Server. Once published, all your reports become interactive (For Charts, you must use the PRO charts and not the basic HTML charts but for tables, it works automatically.)

Once you publish it on the Jasper Server, the features that you get are:

1. Sort button with various types
2. Export the Report to many formats (PDF, XML, etc - more than 10).
3. Zoom IN and Zoom Out.
4. Bubble for your charts making them interactive, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, interactivity is possible in Jasper Reports, but the thing is that you need a Jasper Server Pro or Enterprise version for achieving this. If you are using a community version, it is impossible to create interactive reports. You can download the free trail pro version of jasper server for 60 days from this link https://www.jaspersoft.com/download

For much more details go through this link https://www.jaspersoft.com/community-commercial

Choose according to your requirement.